# "Message id [-13992] was not saved - Auto log cache is too small to contain the message" error with vugen

Tags: c, loadrunner, vugen

I was running a test on LoadRunner vugen when I got the error:

> "Message id [-13992] was not saved - Auto log cache is too small to
>   contain the message"

The script fails at the block of code written here below:

```
int m, i;    
lr_save_string("","a_buf")
m = atoi(lr_eval_string("{dcDownloads_count}"))
for(i=0;i<=m;i++)
{
   if(i<m)
      lr_param_sprintf("a_buf",do something manipulating a_buf)
   else
      lr_param_sprintf("a_buf", do some other things with a_buf)
      lr_param_sprintf(("a_buf", do some other things with a_buf)  /*the same above     sprintf statement was copied by mistake somehow*/
}
```

I was able to realise that the same sprintf statement was written twice outside of the if..else block. I just removed it and the script worked fine.

But my question is: why did I get the mentioned error with the above code ?
I thought "a_buf" would be overwritten with the same statement everytime after coming out of the if.. else block and I might have got the error in the output which might have resulted in my web request failing or not downloading the required records.
Why would I get this runtime error? What does it mean?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The message means an internal buffer used for saving messages is not large enough.

Solution: 
Set AutoLogBufferSize in the log section in your default.cfg file. 
Following sample set it to 999 KB

[Log]

AutoLogBufferSize=999

Comment: Whenever you do this you will be shaping the minimum resource pool per virtual user.  In the case of 999KB, at close to a MB for a set aside.   Consider what you need and not be generous considering you are going to be running multiple virtual users per host and you don't want to wind up in a situation where your virtual users are swapping themselves to death or you run out of memory altogether.